# Selecting listView item programatically not working

Tags: c#, windows, listview, visual-studio-2012

I have a method in a Windows Forms Application, PaymentInfo, that populates a label from a subitem in `listView1` after the listView has been populated:

```
internal void PaymentInfo()
{
        label3.Text = "Amount Paid: " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text.ToString();
        label3.Refresh();
        label6.Text = "Payment Type: " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[5].Text.ToString();
        label6.Refresh();
}
```

When `listView1` is populated, I try to call the method using the following:

```
 listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
 listView1.Items[0].Focused = true;
 PaymentInfo();
```

This effectively selects the first item in the list, but when it tries to run PaymentInfo, I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` at the line that starts `label3.Text`, with the detail that

> "InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'."

I also call PaymentInfo with `listView1_MouseClick`, and it works fine.  I checked a couple other things and noticed that even though I programmatically select the item, `SelectedItems.Count` returns `0`.  Why would this be?  Thanks!

Comment: Include the code for PaymentInfo(). Pretty Please?

Comment: try listView1.Select() before call to PaymentInfo()

Comment: Why are you programatically selecting an item? Only so this function should work, or for visual reason as well?

Comment: @ManishMishra, thanks for the suggestion.  It did not work.

Comment: @user574632, yes to both.  I would like for an item to be selected once the listView is populated, and I would also like the other information to populate from the selected item in the listView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly why, but the only way it would work was to put the code in the Load event.

```
private void PastPayment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
        listView1.Items[0].Focused = true;
        PaymentInfo();
        PopDetails();
        this.listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += listView1_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
```